# HTTP Error 404: Not Found urllib.request.urlretrieve

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, urllib

unsure why this error is occurring when the link works. When I click the link I am taken to the raw data however when I run the code I get the 404 error.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import tarfile
from six.moves import urllib
DOWNLOAD_ROOT = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/isaiahxcruz/Datasets/master/TSLA_data" 
TESLA_PATH = os.path.join("datasets", "tesla")
TESLA_URL = DOWNLOAD_ROOT + "datasets/tesla/tesla.tgz"
def fetch_tesla_data(tesla_url=TESLA_URL, tesla_path=TESLA_PATH): 
    if not os.path.isdir(tesla_path):
        os.makedirs(tesla_path)
    tgz_path = os.path.join(tesla_path, "tesla.tgz") 
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(tesla_url, tgz_path) 
    tesla_tgz = tarfile.open(tgz_path) 
    tesla_tgz.extractall(path=tesla_path) 
    tesla_tgz.close()
fetch_tesla_data()
```

Comment: It is not true that _"the link works"_. Try `print(tesla_url)` and see what the link is.

Comment: `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/isaiahxcruz/Datasets/master/TSLA_data` works, but none of the combinations I could think of with the various bits of text you have there work. Please provide the full URL where you expect your code to be going (and that does indeed work).

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: that is the correct url. I changed the code based on your feedback but I am getting stuck retrieving the file.

Comment: this url gives you raw text instead of `.tgz` and you don't need `tarfile`

Comment: put code in question. Comment can't format it.

Answer (score 0):

The URL that you made was wrong.
TESLA_URL is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/isaiahxcruz/Datasets/master/TSLA_datadatasets/tesla/tesla.tgz

The actual URL is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/isaiahxcruz/Datasets/master/TSLA_data

You added a few words to the URL that makes it different from the original.

Simply modify your code to the below

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import tarfile
from six.moves import urllib 

TESLA_PATH = os.path.join("datasets", "tesla")

# This is what I changed
# I got rid of DOWNLOAD_ROOT and just threw the link in TESLA_URL
TESLA_URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/isaiahxcruz/Datasets/master/TSLA_data"

def fetch_tesla_data(tesla_url=TESLA_URL, tesla_path=TESLA_PATH): 
    if not os.path.isdir(tesla_path):
        os.makedirs(tesla_path)
    tgz_path = os.path.join(tesla_path, "tesla.tgz") 
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(tesla_url, tgz_path) 
    tesla_tgz = tarfile.open(tgz_path) 
    tesla_tgz.extractall(path=tesla_path) 
    tesla_tgz.close()

fetch_tesla_data()
```

Comment: now you have correct URL but it gives raw text instead of `.tgz` so you don't need to use `tarfile` and extract it.

Comment: just save it as a .csv. by the look of the last commit the author made, the file seems to be a .csv

Comment: how else could I extract it

Comment: @IsaiahCruz you don't need to extra it - it is not compressed. You have to write it as is.

Comment: thanks for all the help everyone I was able to figure it out [EDIT: I lied]

Comment: Just change the URL. All you need to know is that the URL has some extra stuff that makes it invalid.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems

- wrong url - it needs only `DOWNLOAD_ROOT` without `"datasets/tesla/tesla.tgz"`
- it gives raw text (not compressed file) and it doesn't need `tarfile` and `extractall`

---

```
import os
from six.moves import urllib 

URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/isaiahxcruz/Datasets/master/TSLA_data"
LOCAL_FOLDER = "datasets"  # or "datasets/tesla"
LOCAL_FILENAME = "tesla.csv"
LOCAL_PATH = os.path.join(LOCAL_FOLDER, LOCAL_FILENAME)

os.makedirs(LOCAL_FOLDER, exist_ok=True)
urllib.request.urlretrieve(URL, LOCAL_PATH) 

df = pd.read_csv(LOCAL_PATH)
print(df)
```

That is all.